# Mull over this!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My suffix is done to stew
> My prefix a distilled brew
> My infix is within
> My outfix makes 10 out of 10

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hold on a sec, allow me a moment to:

> **RUMINATE**!

*My suffix is done to stew*

> Stew can be eaten, i.e. **ATE**.

*My prefix a distilled brew*

> **[RUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rum)** is a beverage made through a process of *distillation*.

*My infix is within*

> A synonym of 'within' is merely **IN**.

*My outfix makes 10 out of 10*

> If something is exceptional, perhaps you would **RATE** it 10 out of 10...

All together, this gives us:

> **R**UM + IN + **ATE**, i.e. 'RUMINATE' - a word which can also mean 'to **mull** something over' (hence the title).

Comment: Hold on, let me think... this looks correct... mhm...